# Is it possible to generate an HTML report for Postman Collection run using htmlextra or something similar, without running through newman?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

Suppose I run a collection through Postman and export the results. Is there anything that I can use to generate reports from the result export?

Answer (score 1):

## In short:

There is no HTML reporter for the Postman.

## BUT:

I have done a lot of hacky things with the postman for the business side. Once I have managed to download Base64 and convert pdfs and save them to the machine after sending GET request. So, I think it could be done using response [visualizations](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/visualizer/). It would take a lot of time and would not be really practical. But here it is in case you really want to visualize results:

### General idea:

If you used pre-request scripts in combination with your tests to save data that you want to display. Then to display this data, you would need to have one dummy request that you would send to pull that data from variables and display it in the visualizer.

### How it would work:

First, you would run your tests using a collection runner. After all tests run, then you would manually run that dummy collection and click on visualize to display your HTML.